# Connecting equipment modules without cables

Tags: connector

I develop a system with a lot of small mechatronic modules which need to be connected to the equipment base both mechanically and electrically (usually AC mains and CAN bus).  Often I need to mount and dismount these modules for debugging and replacement. I like reliable cables with circular connectors, but they take too much space, cables tend to clutter up  the work zone, and it is annoying to connect them many times in not-so-convenient places.

I am looking for electrical connectors which can self-center and reliably connect when I need to care just about mechanical connection. I even made one from teapot connectors :) But I hope there are more conventional ways to do it. What are them? What is the right term for this type of connection and what parts are usually used to do it?

[image: Teapot connector embedded]

Here is connector I found in the transport card validator. Unfortunately I could not find its suppliers and even specification on the Internet.

[image: Connector from transport card validator.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "standard" name for such. You'd probably looking for "panel mount" connectors "for robotics usage" or for "automotive" industry; trick is getting the latter, due to mass production they're probably cheaper than expected.

I just did a somewhat "random" clicking around on mouser.com [yielding this list](https://eu.mouser.com/Connectors/Automotive-Connectors/_/N-1ehb5Z1yzvvqx?P=1yzuul3Z1z0x9zoZ1z0yxz4&Rl=1ehb5ZerajZ1yvgcgzZ1yq3a7wSGT&Ns=Pricing%7c0).

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for connectors with both sides mounted on panels. However, searching with words offered by you, I came to some good search requests like "rack to panel connectors", "panel to panel connector", "draw out electric connector". But nevertheless I did not find the forementioned connector, thus I suggest there can be some better eays to search.

Comment: I honestly don't know what else you'd look for.